# javascript for image resize is not working in IE?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The below given code resizes an image to 160x160 and works fine for Firefox & Chrome but not for Internet Explorer. Why?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#imagePreview img').each(function() {
        $('#imagePreview img').each(function() {
            var maxWidth = 160;             // Max width for the image
            var maxHeight = 160;            // Max height for the image
            var ratio = 0;                  // Used for aspect ratio
            var width = $(this).width();    // Current image width
            var height = $(this).height();  // Current image height

            // Check if the current width is larger than the max
            if(width > maxWidth){
                ratio = maxWidth / width;   
                $(this).css("width", maxWidth);         // Set new width
                $(this).css("height", height * ratio);  // Scale height based on ratio
                height = height * ratio;                // Reset height to match scaled image
                width = width * ratio;                  // Reset width to match scaled image
            }

            // Check if current height is larger than max
            if(height > maxHeight){
                ratio = maxHeight / height; 
                $(this).css("height", maxHeight);   // Set new height
                $(this).css("width", width * ratio);    // Scale width based on ratio
                width = width * ratio;    // Reset width to match scaled image
            }
        }); 
    });
});
```

Comment: Why two each functions...

Comment: why you have added the line $('#imagePreview img').each(function() { two times in code.

Comment: Always provide a demo for HTML, CSS, JS related question & answers: [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not waiting for the images to be loaded, so they're not guaranteed to have a size (depending on whether they're cached).

You should replace

```
$(document).ready(function() {
```

with

```
$(document).load(function() {
```

This being said, it looks like you could replace the whole with this style :

```
#imagePreview img {
   max-width: 160px;
   max-height: 160px;
}
```

(see [demonstration](http://jsbin.com/uyetav/2/edit))